# Change tile of list elements

Tags: python, list, python-3.8

Suppose I have this list:

```
l = ['Car', '456', 'Travel', '47', '67']
```

My desired result is this:

```
l = ['Car', 456, 'Travel', 47, 67]
```

How may I go about doing that?

Comment: Well what have you tried so far? Please reference https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: So, you want to convert every string that is the string _representation_ of an integer to an _actual_ integer. Now, how would you go about converting a single string `"456"` to the integer `456`? What function (actually, class) would you use and how this conversion may fail?

Answer (score 2):

```py
l = ['Car', '456', 'Travel', '47', '67']
print(l)
l = [int(s) if s.isdecimal() else s for s in l]
print(l)
```

output:

```
['Car', '456', 'Travel', '47', '67']
['Car', 456, 'Travel', 47, 67]
```